# Powerpoint slideshow not operating the same when launching via a Powershell script verses Windows Explorer

Tags: .net, powershell, powerpoint, comobject

**Background:** Im trying to use Powershell code to fire up and manage a Powerpoint Slideshow presentation (.ppsx files). The slideshows are set up such that a single slide contains links to all the other .ppsx files.

Outside of Powershell, I can double click on the .ppsx file, as expected, it fires up in full screen mode, with one instance of PowerPoint. When I exit (either via the ESC key or an 'end show' button on the main slide) the Show closes and Powerpoint quits.

**The issue:**
However, when I start up the Show via my Powershell script the initial display looks correct (fullscreen show mode) but there are two instances of PowerPoint, one displaying the Show slide, one displaying the full Powerpoint app. When I exit the Show, the full Powerpoint instance is still running, also allowing slide editing (not intended for users to see or edit).

As mentioned, I simply want to match the same behavior that I get by double-clicking on the Presentation.

**The sample code is below.**

I have searched for answers to this problem, in multiple ways, tried multiple suggestions from the Web and have yet to find success.

Obviously, relatively new to coding with Powershell/.Net framework objects. And I certainly do not consider myself an experienced PowerPoint user.

Hoping this group can enlighten me to what Im missing in terms of the code below.

```
Add-Type -AssemblyName Office  ### Are there other assemblies I need here? 

$app         = New-Object -ComObject PowerPoint.Application
$file        = "C:\User\jtest\jshow.ppsx"
$pptPres     = $app.Presentations.Open($file)

$pptPres.SlideShowSettings.StartingSlide = 1
$pptPres.SlideShowSettings.EndingSlide   = $pptPres.Slides.Count

$runSlides= $pptPres.SlideShowSettings.Run()
$runSlides.View.CurrentShowPosition
```

I have tried to add these enums in prior to calling Run() but get errors indicating "`term not recognized`"; so maybe I am missing something else that might be effecting the expected startup behavior?

```
$app.Visible = msoTrue
$pptPres.SlideShowSettings.AdvanceMode = ppSlideShowManualAdvance
$pptPres.SlideShowSettings.ShowType    = ppShowTypeKiosk
```

Any advice on things to know for exit clean up are welcome too

Comment: I don't have PowerPoint on hand, but is there any reason you couldn't just open the file directly with PowerPoint? Eg. `"C:\Program Files\Microsoft Office\Office14\POWERPNT.exe" /S "$file"`
[Office Command Line Switches](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Command-line-switches-for-Microsoft-Office-products-079164CD-4EF5-4178-B235-441737DEB3A6#ID0EAABAAA=PowerPoint,_PowerPoint_Viewer)

Comment: Not the same version of PPT is on every machine. I'd rather stay away from hardwired paths to apps. Besides, there are other actions planned beyond this simple example requiring access to the app and pres. objects.